# Elementary Doubt about Differential Forms and wedge product

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms

I'm working through Browder's *Mathematical Analysis*
 (http://www.springer.com/in/book/9780387946146) and am having a bit of trouble being convinced by one of his definitions.

On Page 288, for Definition 13.5, he says: 
Let $\omega_0 = dx^1 \wedge \dots \wedge dx^n$; for each $j, 1\leq j \leq n$, we put 
$$\eta^j = (-1)^j dx^1 \wedge dx^{j-1} \wedge dx^{j+1} \dots \wedge dx^n$$

The $(-1)^j$ is justified so that $dx^j \wedge \eta^j = \omega_0$.

My doubt is that: ***Shouldn't it be  $(-1)^{j-1}$*?**

I test Browder's definition with the $j =1, 2$ cases to get: 
$$dx^1 \wedge (-1)^1 dx^2\wedge \dots \wedge dx^n = -\omega_0 $$ and 
$$dx^2 \wedge (-1)^2 dx^1\wedge dx^3 \wedge \dots \wedge dx^n = -\omega_0$$

Each time, I swap positions of $dx^i$s, I multiply by $(-1)$. In the first case, no swapping was required and in the second case, one swap was required. Essentially, what I'm asserting is that in the general case, $j-1$ swaps are required so why are we multiplying the $\eta^j$ expression by $(-1)^j$  instead of $(-1)^{j-1}$?

Comment: Seems to me that you are correct.

Comment: I think you're right. And shouldn't it be $dx^j\wedge \eta^j=\omega_0$ instead of $\eta^k$ too? If $j\neq k$, $dx^j\wedge \eta^k=0$ regardless of sign.

Comment: @IvoTerek I've corrected the $k$ and $j$ over $\eta$, that was a typo. Thanks!

Comment: @user247381: Yes, you are correct.